# How to add join based on conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, subquery, inner-join, derived-table

How to set joins based on conditions, I am trying to use if or case for doing this, how can I achieve this. mysql error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
SET @sUserId = 15;

SELECT userClip.userId
FROM
  ( select if(@sUserId > 0 ,(select * from groups),(select * from otherGroups))folderId)abc
INNER JOIN userClip
on abc.folderId = userClip.folderId
```

Comment: Try to put IF before the SELECT, and use two queries (one per each case), instead of single.

Comment: syntax error if i put if before select, will u give an example of it

Answer (score 0):

You could split your condition into two LEFT JOINS. This should work since your @sUserId can't be > and <= 0 at the same time.
I also changed `userClip` to `userFolder` because it looked like you mixed those up (please give feedback if not).

**TWO LEFT_JOINS:**

```
SELECT userFolder.userId
FROM
 userFolder 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM groups) as abc   
on(@sUserId>0 and abc.folderId = userFolder.folderId)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM otherGroups) as bcd 
on(@sUserId>=0 and bcd.folderId = userFolder.folderId)
```

Comment: will try & let you know